# std::tuple as class member

Tags: c++, templates, stl

How to create an object with member of type `std::tuple`?

I tried to compile this code.

```
  6 template <class ... T>
  7 class Iterator
  8 {
  9 public:
 10         Iterator(T ... args)
 11                 : tuple_(std::make_tuple(args))
 12         {
 13         }
 14 
 15 private:
 16         std::tuple<T ...> tuple_;
 17 };
```

But it is unable to compile with the following error.

```
variadic.cpp: In constructor ‘Iterator<T>::Iterator(T ...)’:
variadic.cpp:11:33: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
variadic.cpp:11:33: note:         ‘args’
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`args` is variadic, so you have to expand it with `...`:

```
: tuple_(std::make_tuple(args...))
//                           ^^^
```

And you don't need `make_tuple` for this:

```
: tuple_(args...)
```